# Problem installing xampp

Tags: software-installation, xampp

I want to install xampp on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I am new to Ubuntu and most of the times its easy but now i don't understand a thing.

First i tried [this tutuorial](http://ubuntuportal.com/2013/12/how-to-install-xampp-1-8-3-for-linux-in-ubuntu-desktop.html)

But on step 2 i got this in the terminal:

> > *chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run’: No such file or directory*

So i tried to download and install it from [apachefriends.org](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Downloading was not a problem but installing it was.

I followed the steps in the FAQ which was also a fail, after pasting the code in the terminal i got this:

> > chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-*-installer.run’: No such file or directory

So, i hope someone here can tell me what i am doing wrong. (most of the times its me doing it wrong)

I used xampp on windows and it always worked for me so it was my first choice here.
If there are others that work better let me know.

Over to you

Comment: Do you know the directory where `xampp-linux-*-installer.run` file is located?

Comment: post the output of `file download`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

Download XAMPP from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.3/).  Choose you correct version, 32bit or 64bit.

Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded, probably the Downloads folder, by typing `cd Downloads` and then run the command(s) below:

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux*installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux*installer.run
```

And that should start the installer.

Comment: It works. But i dont have permissions to add or delete anything to htdocs. How do i solve that? It says owner: root.

Comment: Are you using `sudo`?

Comment: I copied your code and pasted that in the terminal, so yes i guess. I must say that i have no idea what it means. I'm using Ubuntu since two weeks and for normal use it's easy and better than windows, but i must say in this case its a bit harder.

Comment: **Problem solved**
I got acces by typing cd /opt/lampp in the terminal and then sudo chmod 777 -R htdocs. I did some research and it is not that hard to understand the commands for the terminal. **Thank you for your help!**